# Attach new azure disk volume per pod in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-disk

I have a Kubernetes Deployment app with 3 replicas, which needs a 7GB storage for each replica, I want to be able to attach a **new** empty [azureDisk](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#azuredisk) storage to be mounted into each pod/replica created in this deployment.

Basically I have the following restrictions:

- I must use Deployment, not a Statefulset
- Each time a pod dies and a new pod is up, it shouldn't have a state, and it will have a new empty azureDisk attached to it.
- the pods do not share their storage, each pod has its own 7GB storage.
- the pods need to use azureDisk because I need a 7GB storage on demand, which means, dynamically creating azureStorage when I scale my deployment replicas.

When using azureDisk, I need to use it with Access mode type ReadWriteOnce (as says in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv) ) and it will attach the only 1 pod to this disk, that's found, but, that only works if I have 1 pod, if I have more than 1 pod, I can't use the same claim... is there any way to dynamically ask for more storages like the one in the first claim?

NOTE 1: I know there is a volumeClaimTemplates, but that's only related to a Statefulset.

NOTE 2: I don't care if a pod restarts 100 times, and this in turn creates 100 PV which only 1 is used, that is fine.

Comment: Can you clarify why do you have the requirement of using a `Deployment` and not a `StatefulSet`, which was designed to address exactly these kinds of use-cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to use a StatefulSet but the only I see to do this is to create your own [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) for your application. The operator would have a controller that manages your pods similar to what a [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) does but with the exception that for every new pod that is instantiated a new PVC is created.

It might just be better to figure out how to run your application in a StatefulSet and use [VolumeClaimTemplates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage)

✌️

Comment: I must ask, why does deployment can't use large volumes like 7G taken on demand from cloud provider and removed forever when pod die? why does it need statefulset? can't I have an application which doesn't have state, but still need a large volume? nobody even need such scenario? in any rate, your solution might work, thanks.

Comment: It does if you the default `ReclaimPolicy: Delete`. However, the PVCs get reused. The blocker here is that you can only specify fixed PVC names in a Deployment manifest and all replicas will use the same PVC name so you have the limitation. They are really meant more stateless workloads where your state is something external like a db.

Answer (score 0):

***The main question is - Why?*** "if I have an application which doesn't have state, still I need a large volume for each pod"

Looking at this explanation you should focus on StateFull application. From my point of view it looks like you are forcing to use Deployment instead of StateFullSet for [StateFull application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)

In your example probably you need ***pv*** which support different [access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

The main problem you have experienced is that using pv with supported mode ***ReadWriteOnce*** you can bind at the same time only one pv by single node. So your pods in different nodes will not start due to failing volume mounting. You can use this approach only for ***ReadOnlyMany/ReadWriteMany***  scenario.

Please refer to other providers which have different capabilities for access modes like: [filestore(gcp)](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares), [AzureFile(azure)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv), Glusterfs, NFS

- [Deployments vs. StatefulSets](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#deployments_vs_statefulsets)

Comment: You can't use AzureFiles because it meant for file sharing, and you do not want to share those between pods, the only option is using azureDisk, but it only supports ReadWriteOnce, and that will only belong to 1 pod. if u want multiple azureDisk you must use stateful set with VolumeClaim template which will make a volume for each pod. but I wanted the lifecycle of the of the PV to be as the lifecycle of the pod. why is that so weird? BTW I am on Azure, and obviously I will not move to other cloud provider only because this issue.

Comment: For further reference please follow this issue: [volumeClaimTemplates for deployments](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93019)